# SQL M:1 relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, many-to-one

I have to make a M:1 relationship using SQL Server but I've been wondering if the column representing the "many" side should be foreign key and the column representing "one" side should be primary key.
The purpose is retrieving information from the table with the column representing "one" side using the table with the column representing "many" side.
Do you thing this idea is reasonable and would work successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've been wondering if the column representing the "many" side should
>   be foreign key and the column representing "one" side should be
>   primary key.

The column representing the many side is indeed a primary key of a table, and the column representing the one side is also a primary key of another table. But there is a new column in one of them, is a foreign key that connect each others(this column is the column that makes the relation many to one, and that is the column you should care of).

So, you have to make them into two tables. Consider the following Many to one example:

> Countries and cities relation: One Country has many cities.

This would be represented with two tables:

[image]

**`Countries`**:

- `CountryID` primary key,
- `Name`.

**`Cities`**:

- `CityID` primary key<sup>**1**</sup>,
- `CountryId` foreign key references `Countries(ID)`,
- `Name`.

And that is how you should create a many to one relation as follows:

- The columns `CountryID` and `CityID` are primary keys in the two tables.
- The column `CountryID` which represents the one side is a foreign key in the many side(`cities` table). That is the column that you should

---

<sup>**1:**<sup>You should have a **composite key** instead of a primary table in the `Cities` unless you want a city to be in more than one Country at the same time.</sup></sup>

Comment: You really should not promote creating tables with the same name of primary key, `ID` in this case; it makes a mess of queries. Since you have given `Countries` and `Cities` as your example what's wrong with at least calling the keys `country_id` and `city_id`? Also you should have a composite key in the `Cities` unless you want a city to be in more than one `Country` at the same time.

Comment: @Tony - I used the diagram that is in my answer from an existing database. But I used this approach, because I used to use `LINQ to SQL` and NHibernate recently as an ORM. So `ID` as a primary key was fine since in my application would be `City.ID` and `country.Id`. But I agree with you in case it is in the database queries. That's why I used it `CountryID` and `Cityid` in the column list. Fixed now. Thanks

Comment: @Tony - For the second point, it was an example, and I just tried to simplify the design.